# Google Classroom - Batch Path

Tags: c#, google-api, google-api-dotnet-client, google-classroom

I have a c# application that uses Google Classroom's APIs and batch requests.

The batch patch I use is:

```
var batch = new BatchRequest (cservice, "https://classroom.googleapis.com/batch");
```

This was working fine until last week when I started to get errors due to Google's changes in batch requests: https://developers.googleblog.com/2018/03/discontinuing-support-for-json-rpc-and.html

On this blog the instructions for .NET state:

> For global batch, confirm that your code does not explicitly specify the global batch path (i.e. "/batch" at the end of the path). If it does, change it to refer to the api/version specific path (example "/batch/library/v1").

And, in deed, this is also mirrored on the [Google Classroom documentation](https://developers.google.com/classroom/guides/batch).

My problem is that when I change the batch url and try to find the correct one, I get an error 404 as an invalid URL.
I have tried the following:

```
var batch = new BatchRequest (cservice, "https://www.googleapis.com/batch/classroom/v1");
var batch2 = new BatchRequest (cservice, "https://classroom.googleapis.com/batch/classroom/v1");
var batch3 = new BatchRequest (cservice, "https://classroom.googleapis.com/batch/v1");
```

All of them get a 404 error.

Any ideas as to what the new Google Classroom batch url should be?

Comment: Would you mind cross posting this over on the issue forum for the library so we can ensure this isnt a bug in the library itself  https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-dotnet-client/issues

Comment: Have you tried initializing the batch request without providing a URL? (`var batch = new BatchRequest(cservice);`)